# How to know updated/inserted record from SCD1 delta live tables

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

We have implemented SCD1 using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/databricks/delta-live-tables/cdc but we can not find the records which are updated/inserted. Is there any internal columns created which stores the date for operation and type of operations? Please suggested what can I do the get the list of incremental data set  so that It can be send to AWS SQS queue.

How to know updated/inserted record from SCD1.

I have tried to research and see the lineage of the table. I could not find anything in my research

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with delta tables at the source, you can get changes using the command below:

```sql
describe history source_table_name;
```

This gives you a table consisting of versions and details of the operations performed.

Output:

[image]

Here, for every operation, it records the new version and timestamp in the table.

You can learn more about this in the following documentation:
[Work with Delta Lake table history](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/history.html)

Additionally, if you enable change data feed for your source table, you can get the changes using the command below:

```sql
select  *  from table_changes('source_table_name',2)
```

Output:

[image]

To see table changes like the above, you need to enable change data feed from the beginning of the table creation.
Learn more about this below:
[table_changes table-valued function](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/functions/table_changes.html#table_changes-table-valued-function)

**Note**: The above queries can be executed only if it is a delta table.